Authorize adb with black screen
I spent hours trying to figure it out and nearly every solution involves interacting with the screen. My screen is black and doesn't respond to touch. I need to authorize adb to access my files and back them up. I tried scrcpy --otg as its the only thing I found that doesn't nees USB Debugging but even that seems to respond to do nothing. I don't know what I'm doing as I have no visual input at all.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-screen
